# How to separate exported data from Postgres into distinct tabs in CSV format?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, csv, stormpath

I am trying to export data from Postgres to CSV so that I can import it to stormpath, which requires:

> "It also requires the CSV file to have columns:
>
> - username
> - email
> - given_name
> - surname
> - custom_data
>
> It requires the CSV file to have comma delimited fields, and fields quoted
>       with a pipe character |."

So far, I am able to export the data from Postgres but I am not able to separate the data across multiple tabs with a '|' as delimiter.

Separates data with a non visible ',' as delimiter and spreads the data across the tabs under their respective key

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM servicers) TO '/Users/V/Desktop/s.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Separates data with '|' as delimiter but keeps all data in one tab as opposed to individual tabs

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM servicers) TO '/Users/V/Desktop/s.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules you cite are:

> It requires the CSV file to have comma delimited fields, and fields quoted with a pipe character |.

But your examples are just tinkering with the delimiter, not the quote character.

Try something like

```
COPY servicers TO '/Users/V/Desktop/s.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, QUOTE '|');
```

`FORMAT CSV` implies `DELIMITER ','`, so that should satisfy the first requirement. `QUOTE '|'` should satisfy the second.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, however, this does not quote the data with '|' or anything. I will post a picture below

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is what appears now]

this is what appears now although I used the code above

COPY servicers TO '/Users/V/Desktop/s.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, QUOTE '|');

Comment: Since the fields `is_signed_up`, `email`, `hash`, and `account_type` seem to be importing correctly, I suspect your problem might be with your data, rather than with the export process. If you `select * from servicers where id = 36` from the `psql` command line, what do you get?

Comment: The result is on the image below. It's the same as what was in the image above

Comment: Instead of using `COPY` to create and import a file, try looking at the data just from the `psql` command-line. I strongly suspect that, for example, for id 36, `name` will be "the e", and telephone number will be "n". That is, I strongly suspect you're exporting your data correctly, and that you just have spotty data.

Comment: Yea the data is spotty, but there are still no '|' quotes in this export. I want the export to have '|' quotes

Comment: Okay, so this isn't about the import, it's about formatting? You can force quoting: `COPY servicers TO '/Users/V/Desktop/s.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, QUOTE '|', FORCE_QUOTE *)`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is the result of \COPY (select * from servicers where id = 36) TO '/Users/V/Desktop/nw.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, QUOTE '|');

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Postgres you're using, you should be able to do it like this:

```
\copy (select * from tester) to '/tmp/test.csv' with delimiter '|' csv header force quote *
```

This will use the proper delimiter, and quote characters. You can find more information on this on the Postgres COPY docs page here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

The [script](https://gist.github.com/rdegges/bd973488f0cafbf71f43306b8b35d803) expects the CSV file to look like this:

```
|username|,|FirstName|,|LastName|,|email@email.com.com|,|{"address": "some address", "scraped_data": "blah"}|
```

Also, note that this script is open source, so feel free to can change it as needed!